# Two times differentiable function and limit

Tags: derivatives

I have to prove that if function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is two times differentiable and $f(0) = f^{'}(0) = f^{''}(0) = 0$ then $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}} = 0$. We have $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(h)}{h}} = 0$ and similarly $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f^{'}(h)}{h}} = 0$ but what to do next?

Comment: Can you use l'Hospital's Rule? Also, is it given that $\;f''(x)\;$ is continuous, at least in some neighborhood of zero?

Comment: Yes, I can use l'Hospital's Rule. The second one isn't given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT.**

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(x)}{2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f''(x)}{2}=\frac{f''(0)}{2}=0$$

using Hospital's Rule.

Comment: I don't think the above is justified, and that's why I asked whether *continuity* of the second derivative is given: the step one before the last one isn't justified since we cannot know (unless there's something I'm missing) that $\;f''(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}f''(0)=0\;$